# Adding date picker to textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, razor, datepicker

I need to pass two dates to my controller as a filter. I have two text boxes in the View where I need the datepicker to pop up when clicked.

I have tried many variants given on the net. I have tried using Bootstrap Datepicker and JqueryUI. But both doesn't seem to give me any output

```
<th>
     @*<input class="date-picker" />
     <input type="text"  name="from" class="date-picker"/>*@
     <p>
       From : <input type="text" name="from"  id="from"/>
       <br />
       To : <input type="text" name="to" id="to"/>
     </p>
</th>
```

**Scripts**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#from').datepicker();

        $('#from').focus(function () {
            $('#from').datepicker('show');
        });

        $('#from').click(function () {
            $('#from').datepicker('show');
        });
        //$('#ui-datepicker-div').show();
        $('#from').datepicker('show');
    });
</script>
```

Is there any specific place where I should add these scripts. Now i have added the scripts in the head. But  I have already tried adding it after the body. I have also added the following  at the end of the layout.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryajax")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap") in the layout
```

Is there an issue with the order of the script files?

And my intellisense doesnt show datepicker instead shows datetimepicker.. But i have tried using both with no result. Working with razor.

Comment: Are you using anything specifically than HTML or CSS? `@Scripts.Render()` Is it Razor?

Comment: Yes I am using razor. I am working on a MVC5 application. Added detail in my question

Comment: Better to tag it so that Razor users might be able to see this.

Comment: Can you tell what's happening in the Console? Any errors?

Comment: i tried setting breakpoints for the script in the console. Its being hit, but i could not find anything that is happening on the button click

Comment: Can you show the part of `<form>` alone, how it is rendering in your web browser, by sharing it using View Source. Not from the source `.aspx` file.

Comment: @PraveenKumar:  i really do not understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Don't mind that. Can you please try using the following JavaScript? `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js`, `https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js` instead? Looks like more of a version mismatch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97529/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-vini).

Comment: Ok. The javascript was wrong. But now i added directly from my scripts folder so that it holds the version i have in my program

Comment: What are those versions?

Comment: Actually it works here: **http://output.jsbin.com/kelabodoto**. The same code of yours.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: `jquery-ui-1.11.4.js` and `jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js` . i have also `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js` but it is not used in the code. just it is added inmy code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added datepicker to your page in this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/zkLc8vpj/

And I am still trying to understand why did you use all those javascript code, u only need to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#from, #to').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: I too tried with your code alone before adding all this code of mine. I found it on some tutorial.

Comment: I bet the problem is how you are adding the javascript in your view
Are you sure you are adding it to the script section of your layout page?

Comment: I think same with @stibay, otherwise this code should works fine.

Comment: @SerhanKarakaya: I am not sure where i should be adding the Scripts and what order i should be following.. :( and as i have already mentioned my intellisense doesn't show datepicker instead shows datetimepicker.

Comment: I have changed the order of the script files and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

So i have found that the issue is with the ordering of the script files. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28841540/asp-net-mvc-5-not-rendering-jquery-ui-css-bundle) helped me find a solution. I added the script files in the following order in the head of the html file

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css", "~/Content/css", "~/Content/datepicker3.css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.js")
```

and in the bundle config i added the following. The complete bundle file is added to avoid any confusion for a future reader

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/Custom.css"));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
      "~/Content/themes/base/core.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/resizable.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/selectable.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/accordion.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/autocomplete.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/button.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/.dialog.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/slider.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/tabs.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/progressbar.css",
      "~/Content/themes/base/theme.css")); 

    }
```

I  made no changes in the layout though. And the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34204071/5243291) has it how to call the date picker.